# Can't switch iMessages on

Tags: ios, messages

I can't switch iMessages ON anymore (it was ON).
When I try to flip the switch from OFF to ON it instantly returns to OFF (I don't see any message like "activating...", it just doens't flip). So I don't think it's a server problem because the iPhone isn't even trying to connect. It's like te switch is broken.

I try'ed/checked

- restart
- hard reset
- resetting the iPhone settings
- changing Wifi network and switching to mobile internet
- there are no restrictions (they are off)
- Facetime works (I can turn it on/off)
- Date & time are correct
- I can send iMessages via Messages on my iMac
- Googling
- Plain SMS messages work fine
- I can log in and out on my iCloud account

I did make a change to my AppleID. Move my mobile number from "home number" to "mobile number" (http://snag.gy/ze6Ip.jpg) because iMessages didn't work with my mobile number anymore. I tried reverting this changed without succes.

Anyone has an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Try logging out iCloud on your phone and log back in?

Comment: Just to be sure: You are able to send plain SMS messages (because a "silent" SMS will be sent when activating iMessage)?

Comment: @Robuust Logging in (and out) works

Comment: @cyphorious plain SMS messages work fine

Comment: @JeroenVdb so issue solved now?

Comment: Yes, backup-wipe-restoring my iPhone worked for me. Just logging in/out didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new (iCloud) backup, wiped the phone and restored my backup.
Not really a decent solution, but iMessages works again and I didn't lose anything.